# Is there a term to describe this "humourous" strikethrough commonly seen on internet nowadays?

Tags: writing, terminology

This article ["Paying Taxes on Technical Debt" on thedailywtf.com](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/paying-taxes-on-technical-debt) has an example of this "humorous" strikethrough that is prevalent on the internet:

> Just to make it <s>needlessly complicated</s> interesting, in many cases, the numbers need to be transformed via some formula before copying, and the formulas vary from form to form, and from state to state.

The author strikes off what they really think, and then write what is more acceptable to <s>show off how smart they are</s> add humour. Is there a term to describe this kind of strikethrough?

Comment: You know you're old^H^H^H have a lot of experience when you use [^H instead of <s>strike through</s>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backspace#.5EH) That Wikipedia link describes it as [epanorthosis](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epanorthosis), or a substitution of a more emphatic word or phrase for one just preceding (as in “Most brave, nay, most heroic act!”).

Comment: @ColleenV That seems to be the closest "term", if there is such a thing. You might choose to post that as an answer.

Comment: I intend to when I have time to write a proper one unless someone beats me to it. I'm not familiar with that term and want to do some more research.

Comment: @ColleenV The definition of epanorthosis is in fact the *reverse* of what's happening with these strike-throughs. If you notice, strike-throughs occur **before** the substituted word/phrase; an epanorthosis occurs **after**. This distinction is important, and differentiates the two, because of the perspective that the reader must adopt when contrasting the two phrases, as I touched upon within my response when using the hash tag example.

Comment: in _Rhetoric, A View of its principal tropes and fingures...._ [1767], Thomas Gibbons defined epanorthosis as _"a figure whereby we retract or recal what we have [spoken] or [resolved.]"_  His examples are a little wordier than the simple strikethrough/replace, but they include some where the second statement dials back the intensity of the first.  
 https://books.google.com/books?id=EPKUzUwwg70C&pg=PA141&dq=epanorthosis&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUoMWm7oHWAhUUVGMKHWn9D94Q6AEIODAD#v=onepage&q=epanorthosis&f=false

Comment: English.se also has at least one answer that uses _epanorthosis_ in exactly the way the OP is asking about: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/310178/name-for-person-who-uses-epanorthosis

Answer (score 2):

The original answer by user30379 is pretty good, but I think there's a naunce to the answer over at [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/408176/whats-the-difference-in-use-between-a-strikethrough-and-an-epanorthosis) that he missed, which the comments made by @ColleenV and @Adam were also hinting at.

The answer(s) there don't state that a strikethrough is **not** an epanorthosis. They state that a strikethrough is **not always** an epanorthosis, but certainly can be.

This is best explained by a comment by @Adam on that post:

> It seems to me that epanorthosis is one way that strikethroughs are used (and conversely, strikethroughs are one way to frame epanorthosis.) Neither is a subset of the other, but there is an overlap - specifically when strikethroughs are used to intentionally rephrase to intensify or de-intensify an expression while leaving a hint of the original feeling behind.

It seems to me that in the context of the OP's original question, the specifically **humorous** use of strikethroughs in a standardized and recognized pattern:

> <s>Honest assessment</s> Tactfully de-emphasized restatement.

**is** always an epanorthosis.

Just because both strikethroughs and epanorthoses can also be used or formed in other ways does not make that fact any less the case.

Viz:

[image]

In any case, dictionaries differ over the exact definition of epanorthosis. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epanorthosis) states it is "a substitution of a *more emphatic* word or phrase for one just preceding" (my italics). If this is to be believed, such a humorous strikethrough would 'fail' the strict definition, as the correction is often a de-emphasis, rather than adding further emphasis. [Wikipedia's definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epanorthosis), however, not only states that epanorthosis is 'emphatic word replacement' (regardless of whether the correction is the most emphasized part, or the replaced part), but specifically mentions "Striking through words is another way of demonstrating such an effect [of epanorthosis]."

Since neither the online Cambridge Dictionary or Lexico.com include the word (and I don't have access to the full OED), these are about the best definitions freely available. I would argue Wikipedia's definition is preferable, both in reflecting recent changes in usage, while also taking into account the origins of the word in Ancient Greek: 'epanórthōsis (ἐπανόρθωσις)', which means 'correcting, revision', and has no sense of a specific word order or emphasis at all. To resist using a word to describe something on the basis of an overly narrow and out of date Merriam-Webster definition would therefore seem to be needlessly pedantic.

#### In conclusion:

The answer to the OP's question is (as originally suggested by ColleenV) 'epanorthosis'.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a term to describe this kind of strikethrough?

No, I don't believe there is.. it's simply referred to as a *revision*, *edit*, *strike-through*, or *retraction*.

And yes, this is seen everywhere on the Internet today. IMO, this usage of a strike-through is somewhat analogous to how people use hash tags, but with the scope of the expression being much more immediate; a kind of way to comment on a statement *while* it's being made, whereas hash tags comment after the fact.

That being said, strikethroughs occur **before** the associated word/phrase, instead of after, which is in contrast to an [epanorthosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epanorthosis) (mentioned in a comment). The two have a similar effect on the reader, however, a strike-through is an independently existing comment pertaining to what's *next* to be said, and is presented in the form of an explicit retraction. An epanorthosis, however, *is* dependent upon the most *previous* statement, and, serves to refocus/correct/enhance what had just been stated.

---

A post has been made [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/408176/whats-the-difference-in-use-between-a-strikethrough-and-an-epanorthosis) regarding the differences between a strikethrough and an epanorthosis.

---

An answer has been provided for [that](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/408176/whats-the-difference-in-use-between-a-strikethrough-and-an-epanorthosis) post, in which the potentiality of any differences in use between strikethroughs and epanorthoses is brought into question, and **the general consensus is that the two should not be regarded as the same, and that they have fundamental differences in usage.**

Given this, I reinforce my response to the OP.

Comment: Even back in Usenet days, you would see things like "I really hate^H^H^H^H leave it to others to enjoy <the other guy's favorite band>". Because `^H` was something that might get displayed if you hit backspace when your terminal settings weren't right.

Comment: So how are you distinguishing the strikethrough device from the second example of epanorthosis on the wikipedia page you linked to? (_"Sigmund Fraud - Freud, I mean"_)  Is it as simple as whether the typesetter actually put a line through the word?  Seems close to a distinction without a difference.

Comment: The Wikipedia link for epanorthosis in your answer says 'The words in italics are technically the epanorthoses, but all the words following the dash may be considered part of the epanorthosis as well. Striking through words is another way of demonstrating such an effect.' Maybe you could clarify that?

Comment: The etymology from Merriam-Webster seems to support the idea of a correction instead of precedence: 'Late Latin, from Greek epanorthōsis correction, revision, from epanorthoun to correct, revise (from ep- + anorthoun to restore, correct, from ana- + orthoun to straighten, from orthos straight, right'